# How To Use Breakpoint With Rails, But Without Compass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, sass, compass-sass, breakpoint-sass

It appears that [Breakpoint](http://breakpoint-sass.com/) no longer has a compass dependency ([see here](https://github.com/Team-Sass/breakpoint/issues/92)), but I cannot get it working with Rails 4 unless I add compass and require it through `application.rb`.

It seems that without compass, breakpoint is not exposed as a resource, so using:

```
@import breakpoint
```

Throws an error:

```
File to import not found or unreadable: breakpoint.
```

My `Gemfile.lock` contains:

```
sass (3.3.10)
sassy-maps (0.4.0)
breakpoint (2.4.2)
      sass (~> 3.3.0)
      sassy-maps (< 1.0.0)
```

I have tried adding an initializer and requiring breakpoint, but this doesn't help.

Comment: I too am having this issue. Did you manage to solve it?

Comment: @rctneil Nope, but I think the problem is breakpoint never registers its stylesheet with the pipeline. Looking at Susy's initialisation code, it checks for compass and if not present, it registers it's stylesheet. Breakpoint just does nada.

Comment: Just for reference, here is my question on the matter: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24963153/breakpoint-in-rails-app