# Breakpoint in Rails app

Tags: import, rubygems, sass, breakpoint-sass

I've been told by Mason Wendell that I can use Breakpoint in my application without Compass.

I have gem `'breakpoint', '2.4.1'` in my `Gemfile` and `@import "breakpoint"` in my application.css.sass but it fails to locate Breakpoint.

Mason stated "Just get your import paths to find the _breakpoint.scss partial and you should be all set.".

I'm a bit confused about how to actually do this.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two styles of using Sass dependencies:

1. Fetch with RubyGems, apply with a pathless `@import 'breakpoint';`, made possible by Compass.
2. Fetch manually with Bower into a subfolder within your project folder, apply with a relative `@import 'bower-components/breakpoint/stylesheets/breakpoint'`.

There is a way to import Sass dependencies with a pathless `@import` of a RubyGems-installed dependency and without Compass: put the directory of where RubyGems stores Breakpoint into Sass' `load_paths` parameter. But you should consider this a workaround rather than a normal workflow.

Comment: Thankyou! Installed as a Bower component.

Comment: And to close the Github issue. :D

Comment: ^ Complete! I did post another comment there too though as I feel that would help people who wish to use Breakpoint but without Compass.

Comment: Just an update to this, the next release of Breakpoint will solve this. It looks for Compass, if it does not find then then breakpoint will add itself directly to the sass path.